# objective c load AVAsset from NSFileManager file path

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, nsfilemanager, avasset

So i download an .mp4 file using

> urlData * =[NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl:filePath]

then save it using NSFileManager

> [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

this saves the file in the NSFileManager directory just fine I can go into iTunes and see it, open and play the video so I know that part is working.

Here is where it breaks for me.  I want to open and play these files,  so i use like i use

> [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:filePath options:nil];

for some reason this always goes to a state of 'AVPlayerStatusFailed'.  When I put a break point in and inspect the error I get 'unknown error'

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1 "unknown error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unknown error, NSUnderlyingError=0x1382f9630 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12935 "(null)"}}

what am i missing here?  or how can i get a better error than 'unknown error'

Answer (score 2):

ok so as it turns out here is how i should have built the NSURL

> [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] options:nil];